# -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set. What it is?

Tags: java, maven

I got a source from `https://github.com/apache/maven`.

the version is `apache-maven-3.8.4`

when I run the code. The main class is  `org.apache.maven.cli`

I got a error

```
"D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=6988:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\charsets.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\deploy.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\javaws.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jce.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jfr.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jsse.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\plugin.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\resources.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-embedder\target\classes;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-settings\target\classes;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-settings-builder\target\classes;E:\repository\maven\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-interpolation\1.26\plexus-interpolation-1.26.jar;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-core\target\classes;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-repository-metadata\target\classes;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-artifact\target\classes;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-resolver-provider\target\classes;E:\repository\maven\org\apache\maven\resolver\maven-resolver-impl\1.6.3\maven-resolver-impl-1.6.3.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\apache\maven\resolver\maven-resolver-spi\1.6.3\maven-resolver-spi-1.6.3.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\eclipse\sisu\org.eclipse.sisu.inject\0.3.5\org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.5.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-component-annotations\2.1.0\plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-plugin-api\target\classes;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-model\target\classes;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-model-builder\target\classes;C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\apache-maven-3.8.4-src\apache-maven-3.8.4\maven-builder-support\target\classes;E:\repository\maven\org\apache\maven\resolver\maven-resolver-api\1.6.3\maven-resolver-api-1.6.3.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\apache\maven\resolver\maven-resolver-util\1.6.3\maven-resolver-util-1.6.3.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\apache\maven\shared\maven-shared-utils\3.3.4\maven-shared-utils-3.3.4.jar;E:\repository\maven\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar;E:\repository\maven\com\google\inject\guice\4.2.2\guice-4.2.2-no_aop.jar;E:\repository\maven\com\google\guava\guava\25.1-android\guava-25.1-android.jar;E:\repository\maven\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;E:\repository\maven\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\3.3.0\plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-classworlds\2.6.0\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\eclipse\sisu\org.eclipse.sisu.plexus\0.3.5\org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.5.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-sec-dispatcher\2.0\plexus-sec-dispatcher-2.0.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-cipher\2.0\plexus-cipher-2.0.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.32\slf4j-simple-1.7.32.jar;E:\repository\maven\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.1\logback-classic-1.2.1.jar;E:\repository\maven\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.1\logback-core-1.2.1.jar;E:\repository\maven\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.4\commons-cli-1.4.jar;E:\repository\maven\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.8.1\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar" org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli dependency:tree
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I google for this error.
I got some answer what let me set vm environment.

when I do follows, I got this error,also.
the environment variables, I user those
`-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%env.M2_HOME%`
`-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%MAVEN_HOME%`
`-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%M2_HOME%`
`-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%MAVEN_HOME%`

what should I do? and What does `maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory` mean

[image]

Comment: Do not confuse environment variables (on OS level) with system properties (on JVM level, defined with -D)

Comment: Simple answer to this: Do not use it... Just build via command line `mvn clean package` that's it... and what are you trying to do?

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to use the source code

Comment: @TacheDeChoco I tried and it didn't work properly

Comment: In which way? Please describe more in detail what you like to do?

Comment: I want to run maven's source code project in idea whitout error

Comment: That does not make sense... Maven CLI is intended to be used from command line via a script and not from IDEA IntelliJ ... and what is the purpose of running it in your IDE?